# How to find the battery type on a server UPS Socomec Mastery BC

Tags: installation, ups, battery

I am in a situation where I have to change the UPS batteries of a Server and I cannot even find the type of the batteries that are compatible.

Here is what I have tried until now:

- I have found the UPS model which is a [Socomec Master BC](https://www.socomec.com/range-ups-three-single-phase_en.html?product=/ups-masterys-bc-15-20_en.html)
- Found the [Installation and operating manual](http://upserve.com.au/assets/downloads/socomec/gb-masterys_bc_15_40-operating_manual.pdf)
- Found the [Socomec Product technical Guide](https://www.socomec.com/files/live/sites/systemsite/files/DOCUMENTATION/UPS_hors_cata/dcg_130023.pdf)
- Contacted Manufacturer but I am still waiting for a reply...

However, I have no clue what batteries I should order. In other models in the site there is a reference to `Battery Type` but in the specific model there is none. You can check the link of the model above. I have not found anything in the manuals as well.

1. How can I find the battery type without any help from the manufacturer?
2. Can I open the cabinet to check the type of batteries while the UPS is up and running?

Thanks in advance.

PS: If this thread is not for `serverfault` please point the right stackexchange and vote for it to be transfered there.

Comment: They have a contact form that you can submit to ask them directly. What a novel idea! - https://www.socomec.com/contact-us_en.html

Comment: @joeqwerty Did that 3 business days ago. Still no reply.

Comment: @BugShotGG Remember that comments are temporary; any such information like that should be included in your question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The downvotes are for my incompetence as an IT guy or that the answer is too obvious? If I had someone to show me the procedure I wouldnt bother to ask here...

Comment: Click the "edit" link and add to your question the fact that you contacted the manufacturer and didn't get a response for three days.

Answer (score 0):

If the documentation from the manufacturer doesn't include the specification on the battery or the procedure on how to replace the battery, it may be that they don't want you doing this type of work on the specific model of UPS you have.

From your comments, you've indicated that you've already reached out to the company for assistance and haven't had a response; really not much to be done then.

The only other option is to open the thing up and take a look for yourself. Obviously this is **not** advised, very likely voids all warranties, and may cause harm if done without a proper take-apart guide or knowledge of the design. I can't recommend this.

At this point, depending on your support expectations from this company, either try again, or call them. Otherwise, start shopping for a replacement vendor.

For clarity:

> How can I find the battery type without any help from the manufacturer?

Open it and look, or find some random link on the internet from someone who has already done this (read above regarding take apart).

> Can I open the cabinet to check the type of batteries while the UPS is up and running?

Probably not. I would definitely not advise this if you don't have a proper take-apart guide. 1. this is live voltage and batteries and capacitors can contain tons of power that can kill. 2. All it takes is one slip of the screwdriver and you could short the entire unit and cause fire, blow the breaker for the entire circuit, or kill yourself. Property damage is very likely if this occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding my 2nd question, the cabinet has some drawers that contain the batteries. There are no screws there etc. Could I just open that lid to see the batteries inside without touching anything else? From similar types but other brandnames these lids can be opened while system is online. The problem is that I did not find anything else for the brand that I am asking about here...